# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, youtube-api

I've been doing use a Youtube-API but I don't know why this error occurs.

I've already looked up unhandled rejected and I understood what's meaning was. but I could not solve 
  this problem yet.

Material that I used

- React
- material-Ui

  Could you confirm my error?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import   SearchBar  from './components/SearchBar/SearchBar';
import   VideoList  from './components/VideoList';
import  VideoDetail  from './components/VideoDetail/VideoDetail';

import youtube from './api/youtube';

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    video: [],
    selectedVideo: null
  }

  handleSubmit = async (searchTerm) => {
    const response = await youtube.get('search', {
      params: {
        part: 'snippet',
        maxResults: 5,
        key:'Youtube api',
        q: searchTerm,
      }
    });
    this.setState({video: response.date.items, selectedVideo: response.data.items[0] 
   });
 }


  render (){

    const {selectedVideo} = this.state;
    return(
     <Grid justify="center" container spacing={10}>
       <Grid item  xs={11}>
         <Grid container spacing={10}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>      
            <SearchBar onFormSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={8}>
            <VideoDetail video={selectedVideo}/>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={4}>
            <VideoList />
          </Grid>
         </Grid>
       </Grid>
     </Grid>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

---

### This is screen shoot.

[image]

Comment: You have a typo: `date` looks like it should be `data`

Comment: @BrianThompson Thompson, I didn't notice it at all thank you. That's working!!

Answer (score 1):

in this line where you are setting the state there is a mistake

> this.setState({video: response.date.items, selectedVideo: response.data.items[0]})

you should use response.data.items .... instead of using response.date.items
replace "date" with "data" .